# How to reference a Scala inner class from the companion object

Tags: scala, implicit, companion-object

I want to have code like this:

```
package test

object Outer {
    import Outer._

    implicit class OuterInt(val self: Int) extends AnyVal {
        def *(that: test.Outer.Inner) = that * self
        def +(that: Outer.Inner) = that + self
        def -(that: Inner) = that - self
    }
}

class Outer {
    class Widget(w: Widget) extends Inner(w) {}

    class Inner(private[Outer] val widget: Widget) {
        def *(that: Int) = this
        def +(that: Int) = this
        def -(that: Int) = this
    }
}
```

I am writing a DSL where I want to be able to write things like

```
val i = new Inner(...)
2 * i
```

I believe that the implicit class will allow the `2*i` to compile and call the `*` method on the `Inner` object.  However, I am unable to get the reference to `Inner` to be found by the compiler.

They fail with these errors:

```
type Inner is not a member of object test.Outer (for *)
type Inner is not a member of object test.Outer (for +)
not found: type Inner                           (for -)
```

The first two error messages suggest that it is looking in the object, not the class, for the type.  I tried moving the implicit class to the class, but that gave an error that an implicit type cannot be inside a class.

What do I need to do to reference the `Inner` class?

Comment: Why do you need the class `Outer`? Wouldn't it make sense (and compile) if you place everything (`Inner`, `Widget`, `OuterInt`) in `Outer` _object_?

Comment: The full code has state in `Outer`, and I will be making multiple instances of it.  If I just use the object, those instances will get their data intermingled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `#` operator: `Outer#Inner`.

```
def * (that: Outer#Inner) = that * self
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  I had not run into the `#` operator yet.